# how to make NSTimer consistent on xcode

Tags: ios, xcode

I'm making a game and would like to use a timer to countdown an event, just like what's seen on Bejeweled. I know that I've to put NSTimer in a NSRunLoop to make it work, since NSTimer is inaccurate. Have tried the following but it still don't work. Please help!

```
#import ...
NSTimer *_gameTimer;
int secondsLeft;

//some code
//called countdownTimer using [self countdownTimer];

- (void)countdownTimer
{
    _gameTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0 target:self selector:@selector(updateTime:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
    NSRunLoop *gameRun = [NSRunLoop currentRunLoop];
    [gameRun addTimer:_gameTimer forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
}

- (void)updateTime:(NSTimer *)timer
{
     if (secondsLeft>0 && !_gameOver) {
     _timerLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Time left: %ds", secondsLeft];
     secondsLeft--;
} else if (secondsLeft==0 && !_gameOver) {
     // Invalidate timer
     [timer invalidate];
     [self timerExpire];
     }
}

- (void)timerExpire
{
    // Gameover
    [self gameOver];

    [_gameTimer invalidate];
    _gameTimer = nil;
}
```

Comment: `NSTimer *_gameTimer;` is global.  Why?

Comment: i called it across different methods (countdownTimer and timerExpire), so made it global.. is there a better way to do it?

Comment: Yeah it needs to be an instance variable.  Using a global variable means there can only ever be one instance of that object.  That is bad.

Comment: then that means I should initiate NSTimer in countdownTimer, and then invalidate in the same method when secondsLeft == 0?

Comment: Ok, I tried it out and it works now. Will post the answer up. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NSTimer needs to be a local variable so there can only be one instance of the object running through the loop. Here's the code.

```
- (void)countdownTimer
{
    NSTimer *_gameTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0 target:self selector:@selector(updateTime:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
    NSRunLoop *gameRun = [NSRunLoop currentRunLoop];
    [gameRun addTimer:_gameTimer forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];

     if (secondsLeft==0 || _gameOver) {
        [_gameTimer invalidate];
        _gameTimer = nil;
    }
}

- (void)updateTime:(NSTimer *)timer
{
    if (secondsLeft>0 && !_gameOver) {
        _timerLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Time left: %ds", secondsLeft];
        secondsLeft--;
    } else if (secondsLeft==0 || _gameOver) {
        // Invalidate timer
        [timer invalidate];
        [self timerExpire];
}

- (void)timerExpire
{
    // Gameover
    [self gameOver];
}
```